# How can I stop my Mac from automatically using my [input only] USB microphone as an output device?

Tags: audio, usb, microphone

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro on the latest version of High Sierra.  I often use a USB microphone for Skype, etc.  When I plug in the microphone, my Mac automatically detects it as an input source.  This is good.  However, it **also** automatically detects it as an output source, which is not good at all, since the microphone has no output capabilities.  Every time I plug in the microphone, I have to go to Sound preferences and unselect it as the output.

[image: picture of sound menu]
How can I stop my Mac from automatically detecting my microphone as an output source — while continuing to have it automatically detect it as an input source?

Comment: Is your microphone a headset with an earphone as well?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue with a headset that I don't want to automatically be selected as input device, so I manually have to unselect it..